# Access nth column of table

Tags: jquery

I have a table with the following structure and data

```
<tr>
<td><input id="c1" type="checkbox"/></td>
<td>342</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>Jeff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="c2" type="checkbox"/></td>
<td>343</td>
<td>29</td>
<td>Libo</td>
</tr>
```

I want to calculate total value of the third column of all rows, which are checked. So assuming both rows above are checked, the value of third column will be 24+29=53

Comment: are you limited to pure javascript or do you use a third party library?

Comment: I clearly remember posting it in jQuery but I am not sure how it became javascript???

Comment: I changed the tag to JavaScript because jQuery is simply a JavaScript library and it can be done easily without jQuery.

Comment: If he is looking for a solution in jQuery it's not appropriate to re-tag it in this way IMO. For example, in a website using jQuery for everything it's odd if someone starts using `getElementById` and other ways of raw DOM access.

Comment: Since we mention easily over here, I think it can be done more easily with jquery and take advantage of css selectors eg:nth-child and loop through using $.each()

Comment: @Delan, for the same reasons we use sub-routines - to simplify things. Having said that, I'll admit that it's quite common for people to confuse the fact that jQuery is just a javscript library but, if you've already got it to hand, why not use it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var total = 0;
$("table tr:has(:checkbox:checked) td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2b59/1/).

Comment: Maybe `parseFloat` would be better seeing as we don't know if the OP's values will necessarily be integers.

Comment: I want to calculate total value of the third column of all rows, **which are checked**

Answer (score 2):

```
var total = 0;
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('tableID').rows).
forEach(function(row) {
    if (!row.childNodes[1].firstChild.checked) return;
    total += parseFloat(row.childNodes[2].innerHTML);
});
```

**The OP asked to count only those that are checked. This answer only counts checked rows.**

Comment: I need a jquery sample please

Comment: You do know that jQuery is a JavaScript library, right, and that this question doesn't need jQuery at all?

Comment: jquery is javascript but telling that this ques doesn't need jquery is wrong

Comment: So you're saying that this task needs jQuery? I just proved in my answer that it isn't necessary at all.

Comment: Yes, but it's also possible to drive a nail using a rock - unless you've got a hammer handy ;-)

Comment: jQuery was a great idea in the days when browsers really differed and sucked, and the JavaScript native API lacked functionality. With the advent of JavaScript 1.6 and up, with useful functions like `Array::forEach`, the jQuery necessity has lessened in my opinion.

Comment: I am not questioning your knowledge but I know that for this example, jquery will certainly make the code more simpler to read + use the existing selectors and loop performance. $.each has been improved a lot in jQuery 1.5

Comment: `forEach` is a native JavaScript function, and so is `getElementById`. `$.each` and the jQuery selector API is not native, and therefore won't be faster than `forEach` and `getElementById`.

Comment: Sorry for not reading your question properly, by the way. My answer now only counts those that are checked, and is the only answer (so far) that does so.

Comment: ok I think this makes sense..but then why will we ever need jquery and why is everyone so excited about it

Comment: There are many nice functions there that add great functionality. However, it's not the be-all and end-all, and for some tasks it's simply unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
var total = 0;
$("tr td:nth-child(3)").each(
    function(){
        total += $(this.text());
    }
);
```

Although this may just end up concatenating the text values together, so it might be necessary to coerce the 'text' values into numbers, using parseFloat, as per the other answer.

```
var total = 0;
$("tr td:nth-child(3)").each(
    function(){
        total += parseFloat($(this.text()));
    }
);
```

OK, and now to handle the 'checked' part of the requirement (Which I overlooked)

```
var total = 0;
$("tr td input:checked").closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(3)").each(
    function(){
        total += parseFloat($(this.text()));
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks belugabob. I have seen many solutions using $(this).closest('td').attr("cellIndex"); What's the difference. Is your solution performing better?

Comment: This uses the CSS `nth-child` pseudo-selector and should be faster as no `closest()` and `attr()` calls are made.

Comment: This will produce the result as a string: "02429".

Comment: Yes, @melhosseiny. @belugabob, you need to `parseFloat` the result before adding it.

Comment: Ha ha - we all had the same thought, at the same time.

Comment: I want to calculate total value of the third column of all rows, ** which are checked**. Can you help? I want to use it with $(':checkbox:checked')

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var total = 0;
      $("td:nth-child(3n)").each(
        function(){
            total += parseInt($(this).text());
        }         
        );
         alert(total);
        });
</script>
```