# Find every x td using jquery filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table as follow:

```
<tr class="m-s-3">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>D</td>
</tr>
<tr class="m-s-3">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>
        <span>44</span>
    </td>
    <td>D</td>
</tr>
<tr class="m-s-3">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>D</td>
</tr>
```

For Each class m-s-3 found, I would like get the third td text in array like this:

```
var result = [
  '20',
  '44',
  '55'
]
```

I tried this but it return only the first result:

```
var result= $('.m-s-3').find("td").filter(function( index ) {
  return index === 2;
}).text()
console.log(result)
```

Comment: [Access nth column of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165596)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var result = [];

$('.m-s-3').each(function(index) {
  result.push($(this).find('td').eq(2).text().trim());
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="m-s-3">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="m-s-3">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>
        <span>44</span>
      </td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="m-s-3">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use `each` to loop each `tr` and then get the text in the third `td` in each tr.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I tried the each() function with no success ! Thank you, I will check eq and trim, I still have to learn

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) combined with the [`nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  const result = $.map($('.m-s-3 td:nth-child(3)'), td => $(td).text().trim());
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="m-s-3">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="m-s-3">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>
      <span>44</span>
    </td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="m-s-3">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector as well.

```js
const result = $('.m-s-3').children('td:nth-child(3)').text().split('\n').map(t => t.trim());
console.log(result);
```

Outputs

```
["20", "44", "55"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question asked specifically for Jquery, but here's one without it.

```js
const result = [...document.getElementsByClassName("m-s-3")]
    .map(tr => tr.cells[2].textContent.trim())

console.log(result);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="m-s-3">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="m-s-3">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>
        <span>44</span>
      </td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="m-s-3">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```